# OOP theory question :: $this->someVariable = $someValue

Tags: oop, nomenclature

I was wondering what this statement actually does:

```
$this->nameInObject = $someValue;
```

So if you're inside a class object that has a variable "nameInObject", are you assigning a value of someValue to that instance of nameInObject?  Is it only intended to last as long as the session?  Does it over ride the initial value of nameInObject?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will override any previous value.

It will only affect the current instance of the object.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are assigning the value of someValue to the instance of nameInObject.

Yes, nameInObject will last only the lifetime of the variable `this` refers to; however, someValue will continue to live on.

Yes, you will override whatever value nameInObject contains with the value someValue contains.